# Error with a user defined report in Oracel SQL Developer - Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a user defined report within Oracle SQL Developer, with a bind variable.
The report consists of a master_report (style is table), child_report_a containing with a style of 'table' and child_report_b which is the same query, but with the style of 'script'.

I am able to select a cell/row of my master report, and child_report_a data changes accordingly (ie, it returns the cells of the same date I selected.

However, when I try to view this in child_report_b (With the 'script' style) it errors with "Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1".

So the setup is:

**tablea**

| id_pk (number) | name_pk (varchar2) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Amy |

**tableb**

| id_fk (number) | start_time(timestamp(6)) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-JAN-23 12.00.00.123000000 |
| 2 | 01-JAN-23 13.00.00.123000000 |
| 3 | 02-JAN-23 14.05.00.123000000 |

User Defined Report:

**master_report (Style=Table):**
`SELECT * FROM tablea`

**child_report_a (Style=Table) & child_report_b (Style=Script):**
`SELECT * FROM tablea a INNER JOIN tableb b ON b.id_fk = a.id_pk WHERE trunc(start_time) = trunc(to_timestamp(:STARTTIME)`

My goal is to be able to select a row from the master_report, and the child_report_b would return all results which match the date (as currently happens in child_report_a) in the script format.

Answer (score 0):

We know what's happening on one side of the JOIN, you have a timestamp that you're using TRUNC on.

But we can't tell what is on the other side of the equality predicate in your JOIN.

Here's a working example.

Parent Query

```
select trunc(systimestamp) A
from dual
```

Child Query

```
select object_name, object_type, last_ddl_time
from user_objects where :A > (trunc(systimestamp) - 30)
```

And the report -

[image]

To debug your report, substitute the bind :STARTTIME with a literal value that is equivalent to what your parent query would return. If that works, so should your report.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply @thatjeffsmith.
I have edited my post to hopefully fill in some of the blanks with the setup.

So if I edit my 'child_report_b', from: `SELECT * FROM tablea a INNER JOIN tableb b ON b.id_fk = a.id_pk WHERE trunc(start_time) = trunc(to_timestamp(:STARTTIME)`

To: `SELECT * FROM tablea a INNER JOIN tableb b ON b.id_fk = a.id_pk WHERE trunc(start_time) = '01-JAN-23`

The expected 2 results are returned (ID1 & 2).

Comment: There's no STARTTIME in TABLEA - so your child report can't work

Comment: Why does child_report_b work then?

The script in child_report_a is exactly the same as child_report_b, the only difference is that one is that one has a 'style' of table and the is of script.

Comment: If i had your report (xml) file, I could look at it to see exactly what you're doing